# SymbolicC/SymbolicCUDAFunction generating C/C++ parser?

Tags: symbolic, interoperability, reference-request, parsing, code-generation

I wish to do some program transformation and analysis.

Is there any package that generates `SymbolicC` expressions from C code?

In a sense I'm looking for the inverse of the `ToCCodeString` function.

Is there some simple open source C (C++?) compiler whose AST representation would be easy to convert to this?

Comment: You can get SymbolicC for C code generated by mathematica by taking this route: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/ref/SymbolicCGenerate.html . The documentation of the SymbolicC package has something to say about why it doesn't do parsing: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/SymbolicC/tutorial/Introduction.html under "Importing from C Programs"

Comment: Other directions to get started with this (probably very daunting) task are: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html and https://github.com/eliben/pycparser (the latter at least outputs to .json, but neither format is standardized). People say you are better off coding syntax-tree-level manipulations directly in C++ against the llvm syntax tree.

Comment: A useful set of references is also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318935/tool-for-parsing-c-into-an-ast/42193709#42193709

Comment: When I was searching for this in the past (a long time ago), I found tools that can convert to/from and XML based representation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SrcML (can't find where to download it anymore). Mathematica can import, manipulate, and export XML. Whether doing this will work well in practice, I do not know. I didn't actually go as far as to do meaninful transformations.